# What is the actual use of OAuth2PasswordBearer?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, fastapi

I am new to `fastapi`. I was trying to implement an authentication feature in it. It uses `OAuth2PasswordBearer` for that. I do not actually understand what's the use of this if I can simply get the username and password as a post request and match it with my database. Please explain this.

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to just pass username and password around, so tokens that have limit powers are used. Read up on OAuth2 [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2)

Comment: so is it that the user token generated at successful login is used throughout the application? So that it keeps track of which user is logged in?

Comment: Not really, I suggest you read that documentation I sent you to get a feel for how the entire system works.

Comment: Suggest read: [Cookie-based vs Session vs Token-based vs Claims-based authentications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/384295/381820)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**OAuth2PasswordBearer** is a dependency for the oauth2.0 authorisation,
when you pass the token url:

```
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl='login')
```

login route will return a JSON response like:

```
{"access_token": access_token, "token_type":"bearer"}
```

which will be used for when ever you want to protect a api, which mean it requires login, you will put a dependency function like: `get_current_user`

which will be depends on this oauth2_scheme, which has the access_token of the currently logged in user, if its able to verify the current logged user by validating the token, which means decode the token using your `secrete_key(private)` it will allow the user to perform further actions where ever your put this restriction ex: create, edit or delete something on your api.
This the oauth2.0 authorisation flow, using the access token.